# Number of symmetric square matrices with 0/1 such that all rows and all cols contain at least one 1

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

Symmetric meaning the main diagonal, i.e., matrix[i][j] = matrix[j][i].

Examples: identity matrix; matrix filled with 1s; matrix where the first row and first col are all 1s

I am stuck because I can't find a good way to take into account the symmetric condition. I tried to simplify the problem into just the lower-left half, but I don't think that's possible. I also tried to think of a recursive approach, which works for the easier version of the problem without the symmetric condition, but I can't get it to work here.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [mathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and enhance your question.

Comment: This is [sequence A322661](https://oeis.org/A322661) in the OEIS.

Comment: You can do this using the principle of inclusion-exclusion. Take all matrices, then for each column, subtract the matrices where that row (and therefore its corresponding column) are zero. Then add back in the doubly subtracted matrices with two zero rows, subtract the triple intersections, etc.

Answer (score 0):

One recursive formula is to add one row at a time.  So find the number $f(m,n)$ of all $m \times n$ matrices with entries in $\{0,1\}$ and $m \leq n$ such that the first $m$ columns form a symmetric matrix and each row contains at least one $1$.  Let $f(0,n)=1$ for convenience, then $f$ satisfies the following recursion: $$f(m+1,n)=2^{n-m} f(m,n) - f(m,n-1).$$

This follows from the fact that the first $m$ entries of row $m+1$ are fixed by symmetry.  This leaves $2^{n-m}$ options for the rest of the row if we allow a row of all zeroes.  A row of all zeroes means that column $m+1$ of the $m\times n$ matrix must be all zeroes. So this column does not contribute any $1$ so there are $f(m, n-1)$ of such matrices.  This is the correction term that is subtracted in the recursion above.

The sequence $f(n,n)$ starts with (counting from $n=0$) $$1, 1, 5, 45, 809, \ldots$$ and matches [sequence A322661](https://oeis.org/A322661) of the OEIS.  Indeed, the formulation there in terms of number of graphs is equivalent with the definition here: How many graphs with numbered vertices exist in which self-edges (loops) are allowed and in which each vertex has at least one edge connected to it.